# Doxygen: Struct fields are documented on two lines

Tags: doxygen

In the HTML output of Doxygen, all my structs are documented in a table, where the field in on one row and the description is on the next row and I believe that is harder to read. Is there a way to stop that?

Example

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
| struct field  |                                                |
|               | struct field description                       |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Or, the specific HTML:

```
<tr class="memitem:a484f4be31b797e3cf9c0f8abb2d71064">
    <td class="memItemLeft" >double <b>time</b></td>
</tr>
<tr class="memdesc:a484f4be31b797e3cf9c0f8abb2d71064">
    <td class="mdescLeft"></td>
    <td class="mdescRight">time in secs <br /></td>
</tr>
```

Desired:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
| struct field  | struct field description                       |
------------------------------------------------------------------

<tr class="memitem:a484f4be31b797e3cf9c0f8abb2d71064">
    <td class="memItemLeft" >double <b>time</b></td>
    <td class="mdescRight">time in secs <br /></td>
</tr>
```

**Edit**

Example struct:

```
struct example {
    double time;  //!< time in secs
};
```

Doxyfile differences

```
# Doxyfile 1.9.3

OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = YES
BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT    = YES
CPP_CLI_SUPPORT        = YES
DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC   = YES
SHOW_USED_FILES        = NO
LAYOUT_FILE            = layout.xml
QUIET                  = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = YES
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       = */x64/*
STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS    = NO
VERBATIM_HEADERS       = NO
HTML_OUTPUT            = html
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
SEARCHENGINE           = NO
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
HAVE_DOT               = YES
COLLABORATION_GRAPH    = NO
DOT_PATH               = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin"
DOT_MULTI_TARGETS      = YES
GENERATE_LEGEND        = NO
```

**Edit 2**

Sometimes it occurs, and sometimes it does not, and I haven't been able to figure out the rules for selection yet. An anonymous struct in a class definition seems to always choose the "bad" path though

```
class test {
 public:
    struct {
        double time;  //!< time in secs
    } temp;
}
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? What is the input you supply to doxygen in respect to the struct? Also the result of `doxygen -x` would be required (i.e. the settings different from the default settings).

Comment: @albert Added the requested information

Comment: I found the information, which page did you see the problem?

Comment: The issue is on the "Data fields" table for the struct "Reference" page in the HTML output